# using a field update to update a lookup field based on another lookup field

Tags: visualforce, workflow, configuration

I want to be able to update a lookup field "FirstUser"(lookup to user) with the value form another lookup field (CreatedbyID). What is the simplest way to do this? Do I need to create a trigger? I only want this to fire when the record is created. Therefore if USerA creates the record, the field "FirstUser" should be updated with the value of CreatedByID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options

- An Apex trigger.  [See Here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm)
- a Custom Button with a URL hack.  [See Here](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html)
- publisher actions with predefined fields. [See Here](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/actions_impl_guide.pdf)

If you use chatter I would recommend the publisher action over a URL hack as PA's are supported and url hacks are not.

My one question would be the use case.  If you are setting the 'First User' field to the CreatedById, I don't se the purpose as the CreatedById field will never change, so in reality, ***the CreatedByID will always match the First User Field***.

Maybe you are talking about the owner field and not the created by field?

Comment: I'm interested in the concept of using PA. The use case is as follows: When a case changes to a specific status then an email would be fired out to the user stored in the "firstUser" field. (I should have renamed this field to "Internal Contact"). The case user can update the "FirstUser" field to some other user via the lookup, so in the case the someone creates a case for another user, then they can update that field and when the case is set to the specific stage and email will fire out to that user instead of the one that created the case, but in most cases the default will be fine.

Comment: Ok, so look at the link that I provided for PAs.  You can set the First User field to the CreatedBy field by default on creation.  The field can still be left open and can be changed, but it will be set to the CreatedBy User by default on creation.

Comment: Lengendary, will try that now.

Comment: Another good post on using PA's to pre-populate values.  [http://salesforcewizard.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/great-url-hack-meet-the-chatter-publisher-action/]

Comment: Sorry, that link doesn't go anywhere useful for me.

Comment: oops.  Try now  [http://salesforcewizard.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/great-url-hack-meet-the-chatter-publisher-action/

Comment: Thanks that works, I should note that users will still create cases inthe "old-fashioned" way, i.e., Cases | New | select record type etc. etc. therefore I think I still need to create a trigger to insert the CreatedByID into the FirstUser field when the case is created (only for a specific record type).

Comment: Yes, there is no real good way top prevent them from using the 'old' method, so I think it would be safe to implement a trigger as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will need a trigger as workflows rule cannot update lookup fields. It should be a very simple trigger

Notice that createdbyid will most likely be null on a before insert context, so it has to an after insert or before update.

The custom button/link solution posted above  would not work with integrations or data loads.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do a trigger or a custom button with a url hack. A good resource for the url hack options can be found [here](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update lookup fields by field updates, so yes, you would need a trigger to get this to work. However, what is the purpose of your custom lookup? Depending on the goal, you could look into:

- Storing the first owner's name or ID in a custom text field, which can be done by workflow
- Use `Feed Tracking` to track changes on the owner field

The second option will however not let you filter on the original owner only.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I want to be able to use an email template that the workflow would send an email to a recipient that is stored in the "FirstUser" field. To begin with this field would have stored the CreatedByID user but could also be overwritten by a case worker to some other user (by looking up another user), in fact this field would be called the "internal contact".